# How to subtract rows in xts

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I am using quantmod and I require to find the difference between close value of today and 50th day close value.

I tried like this

```
library(quantmod) 
tickers = 'AAPL'
symbol = getSymbols(tickers,from="2014-04-01",auto.assign=F)
change =(tail(Cl(symbol), 50)[1]-tail(Cl(symbol), 1)[1])
change
```

but I am not able to subtract it and getting this error

```
Data:
numeric(0)

Index:
numeric(0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For xts objects, the binary math and logical operators always align the two objects by their indexes before performing the operation. Therefore, you need to use `lag` to appropriately align the index values if you want to use those operators on observations at different timestamps.

```
require(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
x$diff50 <- lag(x$Close, 50) - x$Close
```

Note that `lag.xts` breaks the convention of `lag.ts` and `lag.zoo` (where a positive `k` references data in the *future*) to use the more standard convention of a positive `k` to reference historical (not future) data.

---

If you just want to subtract a scalar value that occurs at a single timestamp of an xts object, you can use `coredata` to remove the index attribute.

```
nr <- nrow(symbol)
change <- coredata(Cl(symbol)[nr-50]) - Cl(symbol)[nr]
```

Comment: Getting this error `Error in hasTsp(x) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL` . For more information i have added the rest of the code

Comment: @Eka: The code in your question works fine for me using quantmod and xts from both CRAN and GitHub. Please edit into your question the output of `sessionInfo()` and `traceback()` (after the line that throws the error).

Comment: this is the code `symbol$diff50 <- lag(symbol$Close, 50) - symbol$Close` and traceback result `3: hasTsp(x)
2: lag.default(symbol$Close, 50)
1: lag(symbol$Close, 50)` . I dont know whether you understood me correctly I am expecting only a single variable result that is 50th day close value(previous)- todays/recent market close value

Comment: `lag.default` is being dispatched when it shouldn't be. This is likely because you have dplyr attached and it masks `stats::lag`, and breaks method dispatch.